# Lower vertical space in \left[ \right]

Tags: math-mode, accents

When using more than one mathematical accent on top of a symbol inside \left[ \right], the symbol appears in the vertical centre of the brackets, leaving an empty space in the lower part of the symbol.
Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\sub}[1]{{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{#1}}} %Small Math Sub
\newcommand{\Cov}[1]{\mathrm{Cov}\left[#1\right]}

\begin{document}
$\left[\vec{\bm{s}}_\sub{n}\right]$

$\left[\hat{\vec{\bm{s}}}_\sub{n}\right]$

$\Cov{\vec{\bm{s}}_\sub{n}}$

$\Cov{\hat{\vec{\bm{s}}}_\sub{n}}$

$\Cov{\tilde{\bm{A}}_\sub{L_\sub{n}}}$
\end{document}
```

This extra space is a problem e.g. when inserting a math expression inline with text.

How can one remove the vertical empty space under the symbol so that the lower end of the brackets are aligned with it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\vcenter`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\newcommand{\sub}[1]{{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{#1}}} %Small Math Sub

\begin{document}
$\left[\vec{\bm{s}}_\sub{n}\right]$

$\left[\vcenter{\hbox{$\hat{\vec{\bm{s}}}_\sub{n}$}}\right]$

$\bigl[\vcenter{\hbox{$\hat{\vec{\bm{s}}}_\sub{n}$}}\bigr]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}

\newcommand{\sub}[1]{{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{#1}}} %Small Math Sub
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\mybracket[1]{[}{]}{\vcenter{\hbox{$#1$}}}

\begin{document}
$\mybracket{\vec{\bm{s}}_\sub{n}}$

$\mybracket{\hat{\vec{\bm{s}}}_\sub{n}}$

$\mybracket{\hat{\vec{\bm{s}}}_\sub{n}}$

$\mybracket[\big]{\hat{\vec{\bm{s}}}_\sub{n}}$   %% optional argument can be size

$\mybracket*{\hat{\vec{\bm{s}}}_\sub{n}}$    %% starred version uses `\left and \right
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put the symbols next to each other and you'll see that the “s” doesn't sit on the baseline any more.

Comment: @egreg I agree. This was a solution in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need that fences cover entirely the symbols between them. Don't use `\left` and `\right` unless really necessary and in this case they aren't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\newcommand{\sub}[1]{{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{#1}}} %Small Math Sub

\begin{document}
$[\vec{\bm{s}}_\sub{n}]$
$[\,\hat{\!\vec{\bm{s}}}_\sub{n}]$
$\bigl[\,\hat{\!\vec{\bm{s}}}_\sub{n}\bigr]$
\end{document}
```

Note the usage of `amsmath` that improves a bit the placement of the hat, which however needs some more help.

[image]

Comment: The particular MWE does not need \left and \right, but is a simplification of a more complex problem. In reality I define new commands like `\newcommand{\Cov}[1]{\mathrm{Cov}\left[#1\right]}` which I use in many places with different arguments. Thus I need that the size of the brackets is "adaptive" (see the edited MWE)

Comment: @user24528 I can't see where `\Cov` needs `\left` and `\right` in those examples. Look for `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` in the manual of `mathtools` for better “adaptive” fence macros.